# How would I turn instr/substr into an if-then-else function?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, bi-publisher

In BI Publisher, I'm adjusting a template that displays sales orders using the extended XSL in Word. Each sales order either has a varying prefix e.g. 'SAMPLE_', 'ECOM_', 'B2B_', etc or no prefix. The prefix needs to be dropped. If the Sales Order number does not have one of these prefixes, it should be displayed as-is.

I've figured out the first part which produces the expected results.

```
<?xdofx:substr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER,Instr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER,'_',-1) +1,length(HEADER_SALES_ORDER)-Instr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER,'_',-1))?>
```

My attempt at trying to add an if-then-else function, however, is not working as the syntax is not correct. I'm unsure where I'm going wrong.

```
<?xdofx:if instr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER, 'SAMPLE_', 'ECOM_', 'B2B_') = 1)
then substr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER,Instr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER,'_',-1) +1,length(HEADER_SALES_ORDER)-Instr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER,'_',-1)) else HEADER_SALES_ORDER?>
```

Comment: This seems incorrect. Too many arguments.
<?xdofx:if instr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER, 'SAMPLE_', 'ECOM_', 'B2B_') = 1)

Answer (score 0):

The INSTR function can only take max 3 input arguments, the way you have used it in the beginning seems incorrect. You will have to add the OR operator with your if condition to check of all three prefixes. This is something easily done in oracle sql REGEX , but not available in xdo.

This might work

```
<?xdofx:if instr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER, 'SAMPLE_') OR instr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER, 'ECOM_') OR instr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER, 'B2B_')  then substr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER,Instr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER,'_',-1) +1,length(HEADER_SALES_ORDER)-Instr(HEADER_SALES_ORDER,'_',-1)) else HEADER_SALES_ORDER?>
```

Comment: Hi Ranjith, I appreciate the explanation. I didn't realize there was a limitation on the amount of arguments but that makes sense. This solution worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If some headers have underscore ( _ )  and you want to get what is after that character while headers without it should stay as they are then you could try  this:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-after(HEADER_SALES_ORDER, '_'), HEADER_SALES_ORDER[substring-after(., '_')=''])"/>
```

which for some dummy data

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Generated by Oracle BI Publisher 12.2.1.4.0 -Dataengine, datamodel:__rakicd_user_temp_59a70a9a_bb5f_4058_8fd1_2edeefb375bc_xdm -->
<DATA_DS>
<G_1>
<HEADER_SALES_ORDER>SAMPLE_101</HEADER_SALES_ORDER><COL_1>some text 1</COL_1>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<HEADER_SALES_ORDER>SAMPLE_102</HEADER_SALES_ORDER><COL_1>some text 2</COL_1>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<HEADER_SALES_ORDER>ECOM_103</HEADER_SALES_ORDER><COL_1>some text 3</COL_1>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<HEADER_SALES_ORDER>B2B_104</HEADER_SALES_ORDER><COL_1>some text 4</COL_1>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<HEADER_SALES_ORDER>105</HEADER_SALES_ORDER><COL_1>some text 5</COL_1>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<HEADER_SALES_ORDER>106</HEADER_SALES_ORDER><COL_1>some text 6</COL_1>
</G_1>
</DATA_DS>
```

results as

```xml
<!--  R e s u l t :
101         some text 1
102         some text 2
103         some text 3
104         some text 4
105         some text 5
106         some text 6
-->
```

No need for "if" or "choose" nor hardcoding all prefixes...